# Azure Service Fabric - Configure service instance parameters using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to inject parameters at run time into a Guest Executable via the Settings.xml file or another means? I have a GuestExecutable which I need to pass some configuration to it - a URL at service creation time.

I need two instances of the service running with different parameters, the service instance information has to differ in terms of a custom parameter I need to pass through . Is this possible using Powershell or, do I need to version the config and create a new version?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following command: [`New-ServiceFabricApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/new-servicefabricapplication) ?

When you create your application manifest file, the parameters will contain replaceable parameters that you set when you register a new application.

An ApplicationManifest.xml example like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationManifest ApplicationTypeName="MyAppTypeName" ApplicationTypeVersion="1.0.0" xmlns=...>
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Web1_InstanceCount" Value="-1" />
    <Parameter Name="ENVIRONMENT_NAME" Value="DEV" />
    <Parameter Name="FEPlacementConstraints" Value="NodeTypeName==FrontEnd" />
  </Parameters>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="MyServicePkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides />
    <EnvironmentOverrides />
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <DefaultServices>
    <Service Name="Web1">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceType" InstanceCount="[Web1_InstanceCount]">
        <SingletonPartition />
        <PlacementConstraints>[FEPlacementConstraints]</PlacementConstraints>
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
  </DefaultServices>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

You would change the settings file using config overrides like this:

```
<ConfigOverrides>
  <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
    <Settings>
      <Section Name="MyConfigSection">
        <Parameter Name="MySetting" Value="[ENVIRONMENT_NAME]"/>
      </Section>
    </Settings>
  </ConfigOverride>
</ConfigOverrides>
```

Or you could set environment variables on your service like this:

```
<EnvironmentOverrides CodePackageRef="Code">
  <EnvironmentVariable Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value="[ENVIRONMENT_NAME]" />
</EnvironmentOverrides>
```

> In my opinion the environment overrides would work better on your case,
>   because most guest executable are not flexible on how you can configure them but generally they accept environment variables.

Then you:

- Upload your application with: [`Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/copy-servicefabricapplicationpackage?view=azureservicefabricps)
- Register your application with [`Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/register-servicefabricapplicationtype)
- And then you register each new app with the settings you need:

.

```
New-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName fabric:/myapp/todolist-dev -ApplicationTypeName "MyAppTypeName" -ApplicationTypeVersion "1.0.0" -ApplicationParameter @{Web1_InstanceCount='-1'; ENVIRONMENT_NAME='DEV'}

New-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName fabric:/myapp/todolist-uat -ApplicationTypeName "MyAppTypeName" -ApplicationTypeVersion "1.0.0" -ApplicationParameter @{Web1_InstanceCount='-1'; ENVIRONMENT_NAME='UAT'}
```

The only down side of this approach is that you would end up with two applications, but don't think would be a problem for you, they will be managed mostly the same way as you would do with a single application.

if you strictly need to run both together on same application, you could do some workarounds:

- Using multiple Config packages(don't think would work well with guest executables, but works well with reliable services
- Using the startup script, where you would add the logic to pass the parameter to your startup exe, something like the following:

In your **ServiceManifest.xml**:

```
  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>start.bat</Program>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
  </CodePackage>
```

On the same folder (code) of your .exe, you create the start.bat file with following contents:

```
myApp.exe %EnvironmentVariableNameSetBySF%
```